# Close all open finder windows from terminal?

Tags: terminal, mac

I want to close all open finder windows from my terminal. I suppose I should use `killall`.. but then what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use AppleScript via `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to close windows'
```

`killall` is to kill applications, not close windows.

Answer (score 4):

This one is similar but solves too, and I was able to drop even the Info windows in case they are open:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to close every window'
```